# ! LaTeX3 Error: Backend request inconsistent with engine: using 'pdfmode' (LaTeX3) backend

Tags: errors, miktex2.9

I just got a new computer and when I try to compile any file on the freshly download miktex I get the error provided below and the subject line.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,dvips]{amsart}

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

! LaTeX3 Error: Backend request inconsistent with engine: using 'pdfmode'
(LaTeX3)        backend.

Comment: How are you running LaTeX?

Comment: i'm using texworks and compiling with pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX. I get the same error when I just use pdfLaTeX

Comment: You are using pdfLaTeX, so should not have the `dvips` option

Comment: I'm confused by this comment. It ran just fine in the past. What options do I have then?

Comment: Presumably you've got no graphics or similar in your document. In any case, simply drop the option: it's wrong in PDF mode.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I appreciate the quick response!